# PIC does not restart in case of power off and then power on

Tags: pic

I am using PIC18F26K83 and everything works great.

But when I close the power source (no source voltage for PIC) and then I open it again, PIC does not restart.

I do not what does it do but it looks like it continue from where it was when I close the power source. Is it normal? Is not it supposed to be restart from the first line of the main?

Comment: Are you programming it in debug or release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but it looks like it continue from where it was when I close the power source. Is it normal?

No, that's not normal (assuming that your code isn't written in a way that it logs the current function into flash and deliberately jumps to there on power-on, or similar).

There is a common cause for your described behaviour. This can be caused by an external voltage continuing to be applied to the MCU, even after its main power (Vdd) is removed. The external voltage then continues to power the MCU through its ESD protection diodes (or equivalent structures).

In some cases, enough power might be supplied for the MCU to continue running (apparently normally). In other cases, there is just enough power for the MCU not to "lose state" when main power is removed, so that it *appears* to continue where it last stopped, when main power is next reapplied.

Make a reproducible test case using your hardware, where removing and reapplying main power to the MCU definitely does *not* cause the expected full restart. Then after you are sure that you have "the problem configuration", remove main power and measure all the voltages on all the MCU pins, relative to the MCU Gnd (Vss). If this hypothesis is correct, you will find one or more pins with a non-zero voltage being applied to the MCU.

If you add into the question a full schematic and explanation of all voltage sources, that will allow readers to review it and help confirm or deny possible problems in this area.

Comment: Bear in mind that particular PIC is guaranteed to work with a supply as low as 1.8V so the chances are it's probably going to carry on working even lower.

Comment: @Finbarr - Yes, that's exactly my concern... It won't take much to power it through the ESD diodes.

Answer (score 1):

What @SamGibson said – but it could be even worse!

If for example you expect LEDs to turn on when some GPIO is close to full VCC of 5 V, and the thing still runs on far less (e.g. with only 2V), as supplied by the decoupling caps for quite some time, then it'll look like your PIC is off – the LEDs won't turn on, because they can't work with less than 5 V – where in fact the PIC is running happily, slowly draining the decoupling caps. (The LEDs don't drain that much anymore – current through a diode is an exponential function of voltage, so you reducing the input voltage only a small bit means that far, far less current is drawn.)

Then, you switch on the "proper" VCC again. Then, the LEDs start working again. You think the device "continued" where it left of when you turned it off, but in reality, you've never turned it off – it just continued to work from the stabilizing capacitors.